# Eigen value and eigen vector of numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vector

```
vals, vecs = numpy.linalg.eig([[1 , 2], [2, 1]])
print vals                                      #Output : [ 3. -1.]
print vecs                                      #Output : [[ 0.70710678 -0.70710678]
                                                #          [ 0.70710678  0.70710678]]
```

I don't understand this results. 
Let vector A be ([1,2] , [2,1]) which i fed into the eig argument. Base on the output,
**A * vecs should be equal to vals * vec** base on what a eigenvalue and eigen vector is.
A * vecs and vals * vecs gives me the values below which are not the same. Why is this so?

```
>>> a.dot(vecs)
array([[ 2.12132034,  0.70710678],
       [ 2.12132034, -0.70710678]])
>>> vals.dot(vecs)
array([ 1.41421356, -2.82842712])
```

Comment: **vals** is 1D array while **A** is 2D array this is why you're getting different result

Comment: Isn't the formula for eigenvalues and eigenvectors -> A * vecs = vals * vec? I know they are different dimensions. In that case, the vals returned by numpy is weird to me. Which is something i don't understand yet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [eigenvectors created by numpy.linalg.eig don't seem correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32926861/eigenvectors-created-by-numpy-linalg-eig-dont-seem-correct)

Comment: Try `A @ vecs` and `vecs @ np.diag(vals)`