# Why is my SVD calculation different than numpy's SVD calculation of this matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, svd

I'm trying to manually compute the SVD of the matrix A defined below but I am having some problems.  Computing it manually and with the svd method in numpy yields two different results.

Computed manually below:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[3,2,2], [2,3,-2]])
V = np.linalg.eig(A.T @ A)[1]
U = np.linalg.eig(A @ A.T)[1]
S = np.c_[np.diag(np.sqrt(np.linalg.eig(A @ A.T)[0])), [0,0]]
print(A)
print(U @ S @ V.T)
```

And computed via numpy's svd method:

```
X,Y,Z = np.linalg.svd(A)
Y = np.c_[np.diag(Y), [0,0]]
print(A)
print(X @ Y @ Z)
```

When these two codes are run.  The manual calculation doesn't equal the svd method.  Why is there a discrepancy between these two calculations?

Comment: Hmm, I broke down the problem element by element and found that if you compare just `X` with `U = np.linalg.eig(A @ A.T)[1]`, you don't get the same matrix (signs are somewhat different). Even `Z` and `V` are different in the sense that the 2nd row row of Z is similar to 3rd row of V and vice versa with some signs opposite. Seems may be there is some problem with numpy linalg. Check the 2nd answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32926861/eigenvectors-created-by-numpy-linalg-eig-dont-seem-correct)

Comment: I see that the rows and/or signs are either switched but I don't understand why this is.  U @ S @ V.T doesn't equal A either which I don't understand.

Comment: The answer is that U and V are not computed correctly in the first place. To do so, just take a 2,2 matrix and compute A using some online tool and then compare if linalg's eig giv you the same answer. If not, then there is something wrong with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the eigenvalues returned by `np.linalg.eig(A.T @ A)`:

```
In [57]: evals, evecs = np.linalg.eig(A.T @ A)

In [58]: evals
Out[58]: array([2.50000000e+01, 3.61082692e-15, 9.00000000e+00])
```

So (ignoring the normal floating point imprecision), it computed [25, 0, 9].  The eigenvectors associated with those eigenvalues are in the columns of `evecs`, in the same order.  But your construction of `S` doesn't match that order; here's your `S`:

```
In [60]: S
Out[60]: 
array([[5., 0., 0.],
       [0., 3., 0.]])
```

When you compute `U @ S @ V.T`, the values in `S @ V.T` are not correctly aligned.

As a quick fix, you can rerun your code with `S` set explicitly as follows:

```
S = np.array([[5, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 3]])
```

With that change, your code outputs

```
[[ 3  2  2]
 [ 2  3 -2]]
[[-3. -2. -2.]
 [-2. -3.  2.]]
```

That's better, but why are the signs wrong?  Now the problem is that you have independently computed `U` and `V`.  Eigenvectors are not unique; they are the basis of an eigenspace, and such a basis is not unique.  If the eigenvalue is simple, and if the vector is normalized to have length one (which `numpy.linalg.eig` does), there is still a choice of the sign to be made.  That is, if `v` is an eigenvector, then so is `-v`.  The choices made by `eig` when computing `U` and `V` won't necessarily result in restoring the sign of `A` when `U @ S @ V.T` is computed.

It turns out that you can get the result that you expect by simply reversing all the signs in either `U` or `V`.  Here is a modified version of your script that generates the output that you expected:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[3,  2,  2],
              [2,  3, -2]])

U = np.linalg.eig(A @ A.T)[1]
V = -np.linalg.eig(A.T @ A)[1]
#S = np.c_[np.diag(np.sqrt(np.linalg.eig(A @ A.T)[0])), [0,0]]
S = np.array([[5, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 3]])

print(A)
print(U @ S @ V.T)
```

Output:

```
[[ 3  2  2]
 [ 2  3 -2]]
[[ 3.  2.  2.]
 [ 2.  3. -2.]]
```

Comment: But isn't it the case that for SVD the S matrix must have the singular values along the diagonal in descending order?

Comment: No, but the matrices in the SVD must be constructed so that the singular values and the corresponding singular vectors are aligned appropriately.  The fact that `numpy.linalg.svd` returns the singular values in descending order is an implementation detail, not a mathematical requirement.